# Add parameter to Button click event

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5, button, click

I have a wpf button like this:

```
<Button Click="button1_Click" Height="23" Margin="0,0,5,0" Name="button1" Width="75">Initiate</Button>
```

And I want to pass `{Binding Code}` passed as parameter to the button1_click handler.
How do I go about this?

*Disclaimer: really new to WPF*

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
<Button Tag="{Binding Code}" ...>
```

In your handler, cast the `sender` object to `Button` and access the `Tag` property:

```
var myValue = ((Button)sender).Tag;
```

---

A more elegant solution would be to use the [Command pattern of WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771540.aspx): Create a Command for the functionality you want the button to perform, bind the Command to the Button's `Command` property and bind the `CommandParameter` to your value.

Comment: The tag will do for now and for more complicated scenarios I will look into the command pattern. Thanks

Answer (score 20):

I'm not overly a fan of 'Tag' so perhaps

```
<Button Click="button1_Click" myParam="parameter1" Height="23" Margin="0,0,5,0" Name="button1" Width="75">Initiate</Button>
```

Then accessing via the Attributes.

```
 void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    var button = sender as Button;
    var theValue = button.Attributes["myParam"].ToString()
 }
```

Comment: The member "myParam" is not recognized or is not accessible.

Comment: This would work with an attached property, but at that point a command is just as easy.

Answer (score 11):

Well there are two ways of doing this:

Cast the DataContext

```
 void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    var button = sender as Button;
    var code = ((Coupon)button.DataContext).Code;
 }
```

Or use the Tag property which is a generic state property

```
 <Button Click="button1_Click" Height="23" Margin="0,0,5,0" Name="button1" Tag="{Binding Code}" />
```

then

```
void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    var code = button.Tag;
}
```

Comment: I would use `(Button)sender` instead of `sender as Button`. In the unlikely case that `sender` is not a button, `(Button)sender` will throw an InvalidCastException, thereby helping you find the error. Your code, on the other hand, will silently set `button` to null in that case, causing a NullReferenceException later on.

Answer (score 4):

Using Xaml and DataContext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataAndCloudServices"
             x:Class="DataAndCloudServices.MainPage" >

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Command Implemented In Code Behing -->
        <Button Text="Consuming Web Services Samples" 
                Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="{x:Type local:YourPageTypeHere}" >

        </Button>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And MainPage Code Behing, this code example is to navigate to another page using the page type as argument, you need to make "YourPageTypeHere" and reference page here.

Then implement code Behind.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace DataAndCloudServices
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            NavigateCommand = new Command<Type>(
              async (Type pageType) =>
              {
                  Page page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(pageType);
                  await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
              });

            this.BindingContext = this;
        }
        public ICommand NavigateCommand { private set; get; }
    }
}
```

Also in your App class need a Instance of NavigationPage in MainPage to Navigate (For this example)

```
public App ()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
}
```

It is for xamarin forms, But It is similar for WPF Projects.

Command could be changed with for WPF and Xamarin: "https://stackoverflow.com/a/47887715/8210755"