# Send HTML Parameter to button click event in ASCX child control

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, events, click

I'm trying to access some page HTML to use for an email in a `Button_Click` event.

I cannot set this content easily anywhere else at runtime (Such as in a [TAG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006507/add-parameter-to-button-click-event)).

So I'm wondering if I can use JQuery to set a variable to `.innerHtml()`, and pass that in the button click. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

To add a hidden field to a form: fill its value using `javascript`/`jQuery` and submit the form via a `Button_Click` event.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how one might do this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
<div id="myDiv">
    some content...
</div>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnHtml" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#hdnHtml').val($('#myDiv').html());
    });
</script>
```