# Style trigger with custom param

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.5

I have the following style in my XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="NumberButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Consolas"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="OnClicked"/>
</Style>
```

I create 10 `<Button>`'s and I apply this style to each of them. The `Content=""` of each button is set to a number 0-9. I'd like to create an event handler for each of these buttons (through the style itself) that will pass in the value of the `Content` property to the event handler in the code behind.

I'm still new to WPF so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Casting the event sender in the event handler to button and reading content might work, no? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006507/add-parameter-to-button-click-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `Content` from sender button:

```
void OnClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string content = ((Button)sender).Content.ToString();
}
```

Call `ToString()` on Content since its of type object.

Comment: This is simple and doesn't require over-complicating the XAML! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help Robert. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<Style x:Key="NumberButton" TargetType="Button">
<Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
<Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
<Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding}"/>
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Consolas"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="OnClicked"/>
</Style>
```

Then in code behind

```
 void OnClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   var button = sender as Button;
   var content= button.Tag; // this is the value you want
 }
```