# Pass an argument to event from TreeItem

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any simple way how to pass `Url` value in     `TextBlock_IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged` event without showing in on UI?

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}" >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
            <TextBlock IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged="TextBlock_IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}">
                        <Binding Path="Name" />
                        <Binding Path="Url" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
                <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Url}"></TextBlock>
                    </ToolTip>
                </TextBlock.ToolTip>
            </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

DataModel:

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you not do `(Node)(((TextBlock)sender).DataContext).Url`?, Or as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006507/add-parameter-to-button-click-event, you could use the `Tag` property as a parameter

Comment: @Alfie, You are right! Please post answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
 (Node)(((TextBlock)sender).DataContext).Url
```

Or as suggested here [Add parameter to Button click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006507/add-parameter-to-button-click-event), you could use the `Tag` property as a parameter.